# Cant call function on Child Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having issues calling a function on a child component, when i call it via click i get always an error of undefined.

my Parent has the following Code

```
 import {MatTableComponent} from './mat-table/mat-table.component'
 @ViewChild('matGrid') matGrid: MatTableComponent;

  onReload(){
      console.log('User clicked Reload');
      this.matGrid.onReload()
    }
```

on my child i have a simple

```
  onReload() {
    console.log('User Requested Hit the component')
  }
```

When i click i get the following Error

> main.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'onReload')
> at t.onReload (main.js:1)
> at main.js:1
> at aA (main.js:1)
> at d (main.js:1)
> at HTMLButtonElement. (main.js:1)
> at Q.invokeTask (polyfills.js:1)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js:1)
> at Q.invokeTask (polyfills.js:1)
> at Q.runTask (polyfills.js:1)
> at Q.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.js:1)

So what am i missing to make this work ?

Comment: Check what "this" points to inside your onReload method. If it's not the component, you may want to convert onReload to a lambda to capture the proper "this".

Comment: Why do you want to reload the child component?

Comment: i am a bit confused... what you mean by this points to ? i declare in the parent via @ViewChild the matGrid so that's why i feference it as this.matGrid when i call the function on child.

Comment: Assuming you have `#matGrid` on the component in the template, it's probably not actually the call itself that is failing, but something inside `onReload`. Potentially you have a `this.something` in there where `this` is not actually refering to the child component, but something else. Please provide the `onReload` function as well.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of more digging and the fact that it seems it wasn't getting anywhere i figured out that the '' where my issue. As i was lazy and just copied a line for a @ViewChild for the Angular Material table and it used the '' i mistakenly used them as well.
The correct syntax to reference the child component is only exported class name of component

```
@ViewChild(MatTableComponent) matGrid: MatTableComponent;
```

Doing so fixed my issue. The interesting part is that the error was not very specific and the smart complete showed the the function just fine.